# Can't send windows between monitors with hotkeys (15.04)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, 15.04, window

I use window management hotkeys constantly, think it's one of the best features of ubuntu. However, I have two problems when I plug in an external monitor. However I cannot send a window, with hotkeys, between monitors. I used to be able to do this on windows, and it was a really useful feature.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the answer marked, though an answer is provided there (with the disclaimer that he is not answering the question asked). I ended up solving this myself by using the 'put' plugin in compiz, available and visible in ccsm. I set the hotkeys `ctrl+shift a` for left, and `ctrl+ shift +d` for right.